# start bpm process when database content changes

Tags: oracle, bpmn, business-process-management, oracle-bpm-suite

im new to oracle bpm and want my process to be triggered whenever the content within my oracle database changes. Is this even possible with oracle BPM ? Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ways to do that, Better is way through Oracle SOA BPEL process by using DB Adapter as poller which looks for changes over the table.

You can hook same DB Adapter as poller to BPM process initiation as well through Composite

Comment: thank you very much. It is also possible to create a bpm process and the database connection as an exposed service which can trigger the process